# A Unix shell command alternative to echo

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, echo

I'm trying to output string literals to a file. So far I've been trying to use the echo command, but unfortunately I've discovered it's impossible to output '-n', '-e' or '-E' (at least not without much complicating the code). Is there any alternative command that I can use to output a literal string?

It's preferable if the command is available in the remote machines I'm connecting to – I'm trying to update files on the remote side.

Of course, I can simply pass the data from the client side, but if I do I need to reconnect to the SSH server after each command.

The workaround I'm using:

```
echo alabama | ssh server dd of=/tmp/alabama conv=fsync
echo china | ssh server dd of=/tmp/china conv=fsync
```

What I want to do:

```
(echo 'echo alamaba | dd of=/tmp/alabama conv=fsync'
echo 'echo china | dd of=/tmp/china conv=fsync') | ssh server /bin/sh
```

I'm passing random strings from a random program, and I want to ensure that the latter form can work with the strings '-e' and '-n' and '-N'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "-n"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, you can use bash here strings (see man). Instead of this:

```
echo alamaba | dd of=/tmp/alabama conv=fsync
```

you can do this:

```
dd of=/tmp/alabama conv=fsync <<< alabama
```

E.g. try this:

```
dd of="-e abc -N def" conv=fsync <<< "-e abc -N def"
```